# Read multiple csv files from a folder in python

Tags: python, csv

I have been trying to read multiple files for a folder:

This is the structure and as you can see there are a couple of csv files
[image]

I have been trying to do in multiple ways:

```
import glob
from csv import reader
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from Csv_files import *

#First method:
path = 'backend/Csv_files' # use your path
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
    list_.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(list_)

#Second method:
files = Path("./backend/Csv_files").rglob("*.csv")
all_csvs = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in files]
all_csvs = pd.concat(all_csvs)
all_csvs

path= "backend/Csv_files/"
all_files= glob.glob(path + "*.csv")

all_files
print(all_files)

li=[]

for files in all_files:
    df= pd.read_csv(files, index_col=None,header=0)
    li.append(df)

df=pd.concat(li,axis=0,ignore_index=True)
df`
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/al3x4ndru1/PycharmProjects/Lucia/backend/printing.py", line 14, in <module>
    frame = pd.concat(list_)
  File "/home/al3x4ndru1/PycharmProjects/Lucia/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/al3x4ndru1/PycharmProjects/Lucia/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 346, in concat
    op = _Concatenator(
  File "/home/al3x4ndru1/PycharmProjects/Lucia/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 403, in __init__
    raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")
ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

Comment: I have tryied even the os.path.join(): 
path = 'backend/Csv_files' # use your path
allFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(path + "*.csv"))

Comment: " have been trying to do in multiple ways: import glob" huh? I think you have an error in your question

Comment: This is a relative path: `path = 'backend/Csv_files'`. What's your current working directory? (You can use `os.getcwd()` to find this.)

Comment: @NickODell I want to use the relative path because the code will be put it on a raspberry pi

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't use a relative path. What I'm saying is that the relative path will be interpreted relative to your CWD, and if your CWD is something other than what you expect, then it might break.

Comment: @NickODell ok sorr, yeah I will try that too

Comment: what does print(os.getcwd())  give you? you should fill in the missing folders to get to "/backend/Csv_Files/" my guess is that it will be:  os.getcwd() + "/Lucia" + "/backend/Csv_files"

Comment: @ShawnRamirez The print(os.getcwd()) give me: /home/al3x4ndru1/PycharmProjects/Lucia/backend

Comment: That CWD will combine with the relative path to produce `/home/al3x4ndru1/PycharmProjects/Lucia/backend/backend/Csv_files` That probably shouldn't have backend in there twice.

Comment: @NickODell I have add it an asnwer to have clearly view

Comment: @AlexIlie Can you add this information to the question as an edit, rather than an answer? Answers are only for stuff that answers the question.